# How to get and set attribute value between "class" and "def" with the same variety name by Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object

How to get and set attribute value between "class" and "def" with the same(aa) variety name

```
class test(object):
      aa=10   ## change value 10 to 99
      def __init__(self):
          self.aa=1000  ## change value 1000 to 9999
```

How to do ??

> 1. aa value from 10 to 99
> 2. self.aa value from 1000 to 9999
> 3. print 99(question 1) and 9999(question 2)
> 4. None of the above(if yes why??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following, to access the class variable `10` (`99`), do `test.aa`, for the instance variable `1000` (`9999`), do `test().aa`:

```
test.aa = 99
a = test()
a.aa = 9999
print(test.aa)
print(a.aa)
```

Output:

```
99
9999
```